# Facebook like counter and FQL total_count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am wondering if it is possible to retrieve the total number of likes shown in the like button counter.

FB documentation says:

The number shown is the sum of:

The number of likes of this URL
The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.

So I thought getting the total_count using FQL should be as follows:

SELECT total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = "myurl"

In some cases this seems correct but other times there are shares returned in the graph object (which are included in total_count) but these do not appear on the like button counter.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ID or URL for the object, you can make a simple call to the Graph API to get this count:

`https://graph.facebook.com/{object_id}` or `https://graph.facebook.com/{encoded_url}`

The `shares` in the return JSON should match the number on the Like button.

Comment: Unfortunately this is just not true. For example http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ does not display the amount displayed on the like button. Nor do any of the numbers here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20url%2C%20normalized_url%2C%20share_count%2C%20like_count%2C%20comment_count%2C%20total_count%2C%20commentsbox_count%2C%20comments_fbid%2C%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Freference%2Fplugins%2Flike%2F%22

Answer (score 0):

on my blog it shows 55 total shares. if you enter the blog, and will count shares of each post it's few times more that 55. pls, can you find what's the problem? http://farik.us